# Node.js decode aes+SHA1PRNG?

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, aes

I have a piece of java code example which decode string with `aes` + `SHA1PRNG`, here it is:

```
public static String decodeParam(String content,String key){
    String decodeParams = "";
    byte[] decodeByte =  parseHexStr2Byte(content);
    try {
        decodeParams = deCrypt(decodeByte,key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decodeParams;
}

public static byte[] parseHexStr2Byte(String hexStr) {
        if (hexStr.length() < 1)
                return null;
        byte[] result = new byte[hexStr.length()/2];
        for (int i = 0;i< hexStr.length()/2; i++) {
                int high = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i*2, i*2+1), 16);
                int low = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i*2+1, i*2+2), 16);
                result[i] = (byte) (high * 16 + low);
        }
        return result;
}

public static String deCrypt (byte[] src,String strKey) throws Exception{
    KeyGenerator keygen;
    SecretKey desKey;
    Cipher c;
    byte[] cByte;

    keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed(strKey.getBytes());
    keygen.init(128, secureRandom);

    SecretKeySpec securekey = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "AES");

    desKey = keygen.generateKey();
    c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);


    cByte = c.doFinal(src);

    return new String(cByte,"UTF-8");
}
```

Here is the test function:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String hw = decodeParam("C6F8437E9D868ED99D8CAD8F6C417858","password");
    System.out.println(hw); // hello world
}
```

But I want to do this in `node.js`, I find that they have totaly different name in node.js.
How can I decode `C6F8437E9D868ED99D8CAD8F6C417858` to `hello world` in **`Node.js`**?

Comment: I suppose the first step would be to replicate SHA1PRNG (look up its documentation and/or Java source) in Node using `crypto.createHash`.

Comment: @Ryan I tried to find SHA1PRNG source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java#SecureRandom.engineNextBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29), but I am still have no idea how to do this

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to decrypt your ciphertext in Java, and then create a solution **that actually offers security, without the risk that you'll lose all encrypted data**. Ignore this at your own peril. Take a look at all the i..... individuals using `getRawKey` to understand why.